# Solution Folder outside solution directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have solution, local TFS folder is `c:\TFS\SomeRepo\SomeSolution`
In that solution I have solution folder `Config`.
I want to store `Config`'s files in `c:\Program Files`.
Is it possible? 
Do TFS allows to map folders from outside or extend solution folders somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under:

```
File -> Source Control > Advanced -> Workspaces
```

You can edit your workspace and specify a different local directory for each server path.  I don't believe it's a fine grained as file level though.

Comment: It's a folder-level mappings. Thanks.

Comment: While you can do this i would suggest that it is an anti-pattern and is something you should look to resolve in a more supported manor.